# Prepend all values in deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, prepend

I have a deeply nested dictionary (arbitrary keys and values) like:

```
data = {
    'a': {
        'path': '/a/a.txt'
    },
    'b': {
        'b1': {
            'path': '/b/b1/b1.txt'
        },
        'b2': {
            'path': '/b/b2/b2.txt'
        }
    }
    'c': {
        'c1': {
            'c12': {
                'path': '/c/c1/c12/c12.txt'
            }
        },
        'c2': {
            'c22': {
                'path': '/c/c1/c22/c22.txt'
            }
        },
        'c3': {
            'c32': {
                'path': '/c/c1/c32/c32.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My goal is to prepend every value in the dictionary with a specific path. So basically take in the data above, operate on it:

```
def prepend(value, data):
    return magic

data = prepend('predir/z', data)
```

and have the resulting dict look like:

```
data = {
    'a': {
        'path': 'predir/z/a/a.txt'
    },
    'b': {
        'b1': {
            'path': 'predir/z/b/b1/b1.txt'
        },
        'b2': {
            'path': 'predir/z/b/b2/b2.txt'
        }
    }
    'c': {
        'c1': {
            'c12': {
                'path': 'predir/z/c/c1/c12/c12.txt'
            }
        },
        'c2': {
            'c22': {
                'path': 'predir/z/c/c1/c22/c22.txt'
            }
        },
        'c3': {
            'c32': {
                'path': 'predir/z/c/c1/c32/c32.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I know I can use recursion to loop through the dict like so:

```
def prepend(directory, config):
    for k, v in config.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            prepend(directory, v)
        else:
            # do something
```

But, I'm not able to change the values during iteration. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what do you have in `else: # do something` ? How do you try to change value? Did you try to change value in  `config[k]` instead of `v` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else` branch, just add the prefix to the existing value, and store it in the key :

```
def prepend(directory, config):
    for k, v in config.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            prepend(directory, v)
        else:
            config[k] = directory + v
    return config
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
else:
    config[k] = directory + config[k]
```

or

```
else:
    config[k] = directory + v
```

and it will change value directly in original `data` so you don't need `return config`.

---

**BTW:** If you want to keep original data then you would have to create `new_config` in function.

```
def prepend(directory, config):
    new_config = {}
    for k, v in config.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new_config[k] = prepend(directory, v)
        else:
            new_config[k] = directory + v

    return new_config

new_data = prepend('predir/z', data)
print(data)
print(new_data)
```